# Reversing a string in C using loop

Tags: c, cs50

Beginner programmer here. I'm trying to take an input from user, reverse it and show the result. For some reason, it's printing blanks instead of the reversed string. I know that `array[i]` has the right information because if I use this loop on line `for (int i=0; i<count; i++)`, it's printing the right characters. It's just not printing in reverse. What am I not getting here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Please enter a word: ");
    char *word = get_string();

    int count = strlen(word);

    char array[count];

    for (int i=0; i< count; i++)
    {
        array[i] = word[i];
    }

    for (int i=count-1; i==0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Your condition is wrong. It should be: `for (int i=count-1; i>=0; i--)`

Comment: What's the point of copying the input verbatim someplace else? Why not just print it from where it is?

Comment: If you want to reverse the string your first for loop has to change. One array counts up the other counts down

Comment: @P.P. thank you, I don't know why it didn't come to my mind.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I did all in one array at first, broke it down to debug it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i< count; i++)
{
    array[i] = word[i];
}
```

You go over the string and copy it, you do not reverse it.

There is also a subtle bug in-waiting in your declaration of `array`, since you do not leave space for the `'\0'` character terminator. Passing your buffer to `printf` as a C-string, as opposed to character by character will have undefined behavior.

So to fix those two particular errors:

```
char array[count + 1];
array[count] = '\0';

for (int i = 0; i< count; i++)
{
    array[i] = word[count - i];
}
```

---

As a side note, it may not mean much to use a VLA for this small exercise, but for larger inputs it could very well overflow the call stack. Beware.

Comment: and you forgot the null termination character (and the buffer is too short by 1)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - did I? If this is why you down-voted, you really are trigger happy

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre He's not using a termination character and his buffer is not too short. The buffer holds characters whose length is known, not a C-style string. There is no need to allocate an extra byte.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Easy enough mistake to make, a downvote followed by a comment from you not 15 seconds later. Apologies.

Comment: lots of trigger-happy people are watching c questions. You don't deserve the downvote, but I'm out of votes for today (seriously), so I may be trigger-happy, but I mainly downvoted python crap today. and the "you" applied to the OP of course:

Comment: Regardless, I'd still love to know what is amiss with the answer. Assuming someone down-voted for quality and not to commit voting fraud.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - It couldn't have been them. They do not have enough rep. And it's the second of my answers down-voted in the span of 5 minutes with no explanation. I appreciate the feedback from you, however. Many thanks.

Comment: (devil's advocate): actually the downvote made you improve the answer. You may not have done that if you got an upvote right away.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - It's a bit of a chicken and egg thing. I usually improve in iterations until I'm satisfied. But I can't prove it's not the DV that made me do it. And regardless, the fact the DV remains strongly suggests it's not a factual DV.

Answer (score 0):

```
// the header where strlen is
#include <string.h>

/**
 * \brief reverse the string pointed by str
**/
void reverseString(char* str) {
    int len = strlen(str);
    // the pointer for the left and right character
    char* pl = str;
    char* pr = str+len-1;
    // iterate to the middle of the string from left and right (len>>1 == len/2)
    for(int i = len>>1; i; --i, ++pl, --pr) {
        // swap the left and right character
        char l = *pl;
        *pl = *pr;
        *pr = l;
    };
};
```

And just call the function:

```
int main(void) {
    printf("Please enter a word: ");
    char *word = get_string();

    // Just call the function. Note: the memory is changed, if you want to have the original and the reversed just use a buffer and copy it with srcpy before the call
    reverseString(word)
    printf("%s\n", word);
};
```

And just change

```
char array[count];

for (int i=0; i< count; i++)
{
    array[i] = word[i];
}
```

to

```
// add an other byte for the null-terminating character!!!
char array[count+1];
strcpy(array, word);
```

Comment: code without any explanation isn't gonna help a bit. You should post assembly code while you're at it.

Comment: okay but there are tons of code snippets which do that on SO (follow my duplicate link). The OP wants to know the problems in _his_ code.